# table.insert doesn't trigger __index?

Tags: lua, metatable

I made a custom table using metatables that automatically tracks sizing when elements are added. It works very well and removes the need for the `#` operator or the `getn` function.

However it has a problem. If you call `table.insert`, the function apparently never calls `__index` or `__newindex`. Thus, my table cannot know when elements are removed this way. I assume the problem is the same with `table.remove` as well.

How can I either:

- Capture the event of `insert` and use my own function to do so
- Throw an error if `insert` is called on my table.

Thanks

```
function Table_new()
    local public = { }
    local tbl = { }
    local size = 0

    function public.size()
        return size
    end

    return setmetatable(public, {
        __newindex = function(t, k, v)
            local previous_v = tbl[k]
            rawset(tbl, k, v)

            if previous_v ~= nil then
                if v == nil then
                    size = size - 1
                end
            elseif v ~= nil then
                size = size + 1
            end
        end,

        __index = tbl
    })
end

local t = Table_new()
t[5] = "hi"
t[17] = "hello"
t[2] = "yo"
t[17]  = nil
print(t.size()) -- prints 2

local z = Table_new()
table.insert(z, "hey")
table.insert(z, "hello")
table.insert(z, "yo")
print(z.size()) -- prints 1 -- why?
```

Comment: @lhf Sorry when I was re-typing my example I made that mistake. I updated my question which has the problem and doesn't refer to variables that don't exist haha.

Comment: On Lua 5.1 your program prints `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That's weird. I was using the interpreter on [Lua's demo site](https://i.imgur.com/L8xrmmO.png) just for this example. Why would it print different results? [You are correct though](https://i.imgur.com/FnAPt1E.png). I don't understand why.

Comment: Lua demo page uses Lua 5.3, not Lua 5.1, hence, different result due to `table.insert` in Lua 5.3 respects metamethods

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Gotcha. Well zero or one, it's still unintended behavior since the expected output is `3`. Any ideas on what can be done?

Comment: Write your own `table.insert`, `table.remove`, `pairs` and `ipairs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print k,v in __newindex, you'll see that k is always 1. This is because `table.insert` asks for the size of table to find where to insert the value. By default, it's at the end. You should add a __len metamethod. But perhaps this defeats your purposes (which are obscure to me).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Lua 5.1 and don't have access to `__len` or `#`. Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Actually, I think it's always getting `1` as the key because it sees that the table has no elements, so it tries to put it in index `1` which works. However the proxy table of `public` still has a size of `1`, thus it tries to insert at `1` again? Is this the cycle you were talking about?